# How to print two images with one click but each image on its own page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm building an ASP website page that has two Images on it like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="ImgPg1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Page1.ashx" />
<asp:Image ID="ImgPg2" runat="server" ImageUrl="Page2.ashx" />
```

I want to print both images with one click.

The image on `Page1.ashx` needs to be printed on page 1 and the image on `Page2.ashx` need to be printed on Page 2.

How do you print one image per page?

This is what I have done but I found out that the `PrintDocument` runs on the server side so an error comes out saying "Printer not found".  The following code example prints a rectangle as a test but it is what the .ashx pages have on them anyways.

```
    protected void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Print CI", "window.print()", true);

        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false; 
        nPage = 0;
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printImages);

        pd.Print();

    }

    private void printImages(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 353, 230);        // 0.236 Inches @ 96 dpi = 23

        switch (nPage)
        {
            case 0:     // Page 1 just for test
                ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray), rect);
                ev.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), rect);
                break;
            case 1:     // Page 2 just for test
                rect = new Rectangle(360, 0, 353, 230);
                ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightPink), rect);
                ev.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), rect);
                break;
        }

        ++nPage;
        if (nPage < 2)
            ev.HasMorePages = true;
        else
            ev.HasMorePages = false;

    }
```

The reason why I need to print one image per page is because one image is the front of a form and the other image is the back of it.  The image size is smaller than a 8.5 x 11 sheet (around 1/4 of a sheet).

Thanks,
Pablo

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to mess around with trying to programmatically send stuff to a printer?  Unless there is a good business reason for this, I think a 'best case' would be to create your .ashx page as a print-friendly page with nothing but the two images on it,  then let the user print the page from the browser.

BUT... to answer your actual question, to make sure the two images print on different pages, you can use a CSS page break between the two.

```
.PageBreak {
   page-break-after: always;
}

<asp:Image ID="ImgPg1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Page1.ashx" CssClass="PageBreak" />
<asp:Image ID="ImgPg2" runat="server" ImageUrl="Page2.ashx" />
```

This will force the printer to feed a new sheet of paper after the first image and before the second. Assuming the images are sized to fit on an 8.5 x 11 piece of paper, this should work well.

More info on page-break-after:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Also, lot's of great .ashx tips here:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks Casey for your reply.  The reason why I need to print in two pages is because one image is the front of a form and the other is the back of it.  The ashx pages have only the image and nothing else.  Now, I have uncomment the line `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(...)` that I have on the `Print_Click(...)` and commented the other lines.  I have tried your suggestion but still only one page is printed with both images.  I may not be using your suggestion properly.

Comment: Hmm.  I confess i didn't try this.  I HAVE used the CSS page break before, with success.  Maybe try wrapping each image in a div tag, and put the style on the div instead?

Comment: Almost the same.  Still both images are on one page but now one on top of the other one, due to the div tag.

Comment: Dang! Well, the order is fixable. But I have no idea why the page break isn't working.  You may want to google that yourself a little and make sure I have the exact CSS syntax correct.

Comment: Thought:  Are we sure that the CSS is being applied at all?  How are you linking to the CSS file?  Or is the CSS inline?  Maybe try doing something obvious, like putting an ugly border around the image, to make sure the CSS is being applied at all.  .PageBreak {
   page-break-after: always;
   border: 5px solid black;
}

Comment: Actually I had cssclass instead of class on the div tag so that is way didn't work.  This lines worked but I see the page buttons on the print out.  Is there a way to print just the image?  `<div ><asp:Image ID="ImgPg1" runat="server" /></div>
            <div class="PageBreak"><asp:Image ID="ImgPg2" runat="server"  /></div>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66134/discussion-between-casey-crookston-and-pabinator).

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't access that Chat page.  My company is blocking that page.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Casey helped a lot.  Here is the final result.

Header code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printCI() {
        var printWindow = window.open('', 'CI', 'height=600,width=800');

        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>CI Form</title>');
        printWindow.document.write('<style>.PageBreak{page-break-after: always;}</style>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        printWindow.document.write('<div class=\'PageBreak\'><img src=\'Page1.ashx\' /></div>');
        printWindow.document.write('<div><img src=\'Page2.ashx\' /></div>');
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.print();
    }
</script>
```

CS code:

```
protected void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Print CI with a javascript so we can print in two pages
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Print CI", "printCI()", true);
}
```